# Laravel Mix: What's the difference between scripts() and combine()?

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-mix

I'm using Laravel for my PHP projects, which is equipped with Webpack through Laravel Mix. I've been using `mix.js` and `mix.scripts` (I know the difference between them).

Last week I downloaded a pre-built Laravel mockup (Laraspace) which is using `mix.js` and `mix.combine.` I tried to find documentation explaining what `combine()` does differently than `scripts(),` but all I found is that they do pretty much the same.

Is this some legacy function, alias, or is there a different logic behind `combine()`?

Comment: which mix version are you using?

Comment: Where did you found `script()`? I couldn't find it

Comment: @CloudSohJunFu laravel-mix@2.1.0
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix (Vanilla JS)

Comment: Well it's `scripts()` instead of `script()`...

Comment: Yeah sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mix.scripts()` is better for combining and minifying multiple custom JavaScript files, for instance, files that you created. `mix.scripts('folder/path')` will combine all nested files and `mix.scripts('folder/path/*.js')` will limit it to only JS files.

`mix.combine(),` however, is better for the concatenation of multiple vendor libraries, such as jQuery, Bootstrap, etc., and is faster. Also, you can use `combine()` for both JS and CSS.

Comment: Thank you. I read the same, but why combine() is technically more appropiate for vendors? It's just a concatenation process? I mean, if I run `npm run production` it won't be minified? I wonder why this command is not present in official docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix

Comment: The official docs are here: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/concatenation-and-minification.md

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. So I think there's no significative difference with `script()` after all. I'll use it as you suggested, just to join vendors.