# Specify the order of scripts in Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I'm trying to combine two JS scripts into one file. One is a third-party library, and the other is some custom js. No matter how I specify the scripts in the mix.js array, it always puts the custom.js on top. I want to put the library on top. How can I achieve that?

**Method 1**

```
mix.js([
    'node_modules/zoid/dist/zoid.frameworks.frame.min.js',
    'public/js/custom.js'
], 'public/js/combined.js').version();
```

**Method 2**

```
mix.js([
    'public/js/custom.js',
    'node_modules/zoid/dist/zoid.frameworks.frame.min.js'
], 'public/js/combined.js').version();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following Mix configuration file.

```
mix.combine(['one.js', 'two.js'], 'merged.js');
```

This instructs Mix to merge - or concatenate - one.js and two.js into a single file, called merged.js. As always, during development, that merged file will remain uncompressed. However, when building for production, merged.js will, of course, be minified.

Also, `mix.scripts()` is an alias for `mix.combine()`; you can use either or.

Comment: But `scripts` is not the same as `js`, I cannot recall the exact difference but `scripts` just combines and minifies, `js` runs stuff in there, I think it uses babel and any other plugin that `scripts` does not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56641455/633440

Comment: mix.js() takes advantage of the latest EcmaScript syntax, modules, and minification for production environments. 

If you need to concatenate and then compile JavaScript files that have been written with the latest JavaScript syntax, you may either set the third argument of mix.combine() to true, or instead call mix.babel(). Other than the Babel compilation, both commands are identical.

// Both of these are identical.
mix.combine(['one.js', 'two.js'], 'merged.js', true);
mix.babel(['one.js', 'two.js'], 'merged.js');

Comment: @KarlHill Didn't know about `combine`, thanks a lot!